# How to hide PHP file

Tags: php, redirection

I have a script to redirect any external url and that works like when i add this

> http://my-domain.com/URL.php?url=

Before the external url like google, url after adding:

> http//my-domain.com/URL.php?url=http//www.google.com

It redirects to that url But i want to hide my php in this case it's URL.php 
i want to make it like this:

> http://my-domain.com/?url=http://www.google.com

Comment: Are you able to rename the file to `index.php`? That way it is picked up as the file when no filename is provided.

Comment: It's just a normal script that i made in php to redirect on other url and it doesn't have any index.php file, actuall i'm not good in php i just tried to make a redirect script...

Comment: The script itself is not the culprit; it's the web server: When no file name is specified (such as in http://example.com/), then you need to name it `index.php`. Otherwise the server will say that no such file exists.

Comment: Which web server do you use?

Comment: Apache Version = 2.2.34, PHP Version = 5.4.45, Operating System = linux